# loading problem in IE using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I am submitting modal popup form after submit that form I want to load div on parent page that display submitted contents without refreshing whole parent page it works in FF but not in IE this is my code

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(){
       var str = $("#frmAddProduct").serialize();
        $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url: "save_track.php",
                data: str,
                success: function(data){
                    jQuery("#digTrack").dialog("close");
                }
        });
   })
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

```
    type:'post',
    cache: false,
    url: "save_track.php",
```

Give that a try